# Retrofit 2.0, request GET to a .json file as endpoint

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Hello Im working in a test with Retrofit 2.0 and one of the test is making a resquest to a url that finish with .json:

Example: https://domain.com/contacts.json

baseURl: https://domain.com/
endPoint: /contacts.json

Which is a file, but I want to make a normal GET request and get the json inside directly

Comment: Can you post your source code and tell us more about what is not working ?

Comment: make base uri `https://domain.com/` and end point `contacts.json`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello I found a solution to get the file using your code and it really works now but I haven't touch the MIME on the web server, I think I didn't have added the Converter in the code I guess. Thank you.

WebAPIService.java:

```
public interface WebAPIService {
@GET("/contacts.json")
     Call<JsonObject> getContacts();
}
```

MainAcitivty.java:

```
Retrofit retrofit1 = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_ENDPOINT)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();

 WebAPIService service1 = retrofit1.create(WebAPIService.class);

 Call<List<Contact>> jsonCall = service1.getContacts();
 jsonCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Contact>() {

 @Override
 public void onResponse(Call<List<Contact>> call, Response<List<Contact>> response) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, response.body().toString());
 }

 @Override
 public void onFailure(Call<List<Contact>> call, Throwable t) {
     Log.e(LOG_TAG, t.toString());
 }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have control over your web server, you can customize it supports `.json` file as `text/plain` or `application/json`. Please see my following screenshot (I have done with IIS 7.5)

[image]

The following screenshot is a request using PostMan:

[image]

build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    ...    
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
}
```

WebAPIService.java:

```
public interface WebAPIService {
    @GET("/files/jsonsample.json")
    Call<JsonObject> readJson();
}
```

MainAcitivty.java:

```
Retrofit retrofit1 = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://...")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

WebAPIService service1 = retrofit1.create(WebAPIService.class);
Call<JsonObject> jsonCall = service1.readJson();
jsonCall.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, response.body().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, t.toString());
    }
});
```

Logcat:

```
04-15 15:31:31.943 5810-5810/com.example.asyncretrofit I/AsyncRetrofit: {"glossary":{"title":"example glossary","GlossDiv":{"title":"S","GlossList":{"GlossEntry":{"ID":"SGML","SortAs":"SGML","GlossTerm":"Standard Generalized Markup Language","Acronym":"SGML","Abbrev":"ISO 8879:1986","GlossDef":{"para":"A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.","GlossSeeAlso":["GML","XML"]},"GlossSee":"markup"}}}}}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for that is exactly my problem but I have not control over the web server, so the option Im going to go for is download the file and parse it.