# How to call retrofit without back slash in baseUrl

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit

I have two activity and in First Activity I am calling api with retrofit

```
 private fun retrofitConfiguration() {
        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://abhi-debug.github.io/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
```

and Api Interface -

```
 interface ApiService {


      @GET("Caption/caption_home.json")
      fun fetchUser() : Call<List<Captions>>


      @GET(" ")
      fun fetchData(): Call<List<Data>>
    }
```

so it give  me a json like this-

```
 [
     {

        "id": 14,
        "title": "Demo",
        "url": "https://abhi-debug.github.io/Caption/demo.json"
     }
    ]
```

Here the url-"https://abhi-debug.github.io/Caption/demo.json" will pass in next activity as BaseUrl of Retrofit for Next Activity.

```
private fun retrofitConfiguration() {
        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(**myUrl**)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
```

myUrl is getting from (FirstActivity)json like this-

```
myUrl = intent.getStringExtra("URL")
```

in FirstActivity

```
 urlForNextActivity[pos] = captionsList[pos].url


  val intent = Intent(context, **SecondActivity**::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("URL", urlForNextActivity[position])
    context.startActivity(intent)
```

Error at runtime

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: https://abhi-debug.github.io/Caption/demo.json

Note- https://abhi-debug.github.io/Caption/demo.json is fixed it cant
have / at end

So is there any way to call it

Comment: show me ur base url

Comment: your base url should be baseUrl = "https://abhi-debug.github.io/" [Note : the url is showing as link in SO comment, so open the link and copy from browser]

Comment: you can take a look at this explanation :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758570/retrofit-trailing-slash-on-relative-urls

Comment: use // this is an escape character

Comment: You need to extract the Base Url from the first json (substring). In this case is every thing from position 0 to the third "/"

Comment: you can also append "/" to myUrl like  .baseUrl(myUrl+"/")

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634466/retrofit-2-0-request-get-to-a-json-file-as-endpoint

Answer (score -1):

Your baseUrl must be in **https://abhi-debug.github.io/** this format.

If you have last **/** (i.e Forward slash)  missing it gives you error.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the "/" to your base url statically or use `.plus("/")` after your base url variable

ex.

```
val baseUrl = "abhi-debug.github.io/" //to add it statically
val baseUrl2 = "abhi-debug.github.io".plus("/") // to add dynamically
val baseUrlNoSlash = "abhi-debug.github.io" //when you have no access to base url
var baseUrlWithSlash = baseUrlNoSlash.plus("/") //now your url has slash at the end
```

I hope this helped, Panos.